# Setting textarea to display:none loses the value when trying to save

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, textbox

I have a textarea where the user can enter in a note. But this textarea will only display if a checkbox is ticked, otherwise it is hidden. 
But when the save button is clicked and it saves the values to the database, the textarea is returning a blank value.

Code for textarea:

```
<textarea class="mceEditorWide" id="txtAddDetailNote" rows="30" cols="50" style="width:100%;display:none" runat="server"></textarea>
```

Checkbox that hides/shows textbox:

```
 $('#<%= chkNotes.ClientID %>').change(function () {
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
             $('#<%= txtAddDetailNote.ClientID %>').show(); 
            } 
        else { 
               $('#<%= txtAddDetailNote.ClientID %>').hide(); 

            }
    });
```

When I remove the `display:none` from the textarea, it saves the value. But with `display:none` in the code, it only returns a blank value, even though the textarea is displaying when I click the save button.

Comment: Are you transforming textbox to rich text editor using mce editor?

Comment: @Vamsikrishna I'm not sure, I didn't write the code for mce editor

Comment: Ok, can you remove class for textbox and check once

Comment: @Vamsikrishna no it does not use rich text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer to this question:**
Still not sure why setting the textarea to `display:none` was causing it to lose the value, but setting the display to the `<tr>` tag solved this.

Code for textarea:

```
<tr class ="trNotes" style="display:none">
            <td class="tblAddDetail" colspan="10">
                <textarea class="mceEditorWide" id="txtAddDetailNote" rows="30" cols="50" style="width:100%;" runat="server"></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

Code to hide/show it:

```
$('#<%= chkNotes.ClientID %>').change(function () {
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
                $('.trNotes').show();
            } 
        else { 
                $('.trNotes').hide(); 
            }
    });
```

Setting `display:none` to the `<tr>` and giving it a class name doesn't effect the value from the textarea.

Answer (score 2):

You could toggle the element's `visibility` css style:

```
$("#someSelector").css("visibility", "collapse");
$("#someSelector").css("visibility", "visible");
```

...and if necessary, set it's height to a sub-pixel value, such as `0.001px`

Answer (score 0):

you have to use attribute disable in the textbox.  then only it will not return anything.if u use display:none it will not the textbox in browser but it send empty value to controller on post

Code for textbox:

```
<textarea class="mceEditorWide" id="txtAddDetailNote" rows="30" cols="50" style="width:100%;display:none" runat="server"></textarea>
```

Checkbox that hides/shows textbox:

```
 $('#<%= chkNotes.ClientID %>').change(function () {
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
             $('#<%= txtAddDetailNote.ClientID %>').removeAttr('disabled','disabled').show();
            } 
        else { 
               $('#<%= txtAddDetailNote.ClientID %>').attr('disabled','disabled').hide();

            }
    });
```

hope this helps

Comment: using attribute disable does not hide or show the textbox. When checkbox is ticked I need to show textbox. If it is not ticked then hide textbox

Comment: no this didn't solve it. Textbox value is still blank

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly get what you are to do, can you supply more code? A fiddle?

Try this out:

```
$('.checkbox').change(function() {
  var ShowHide = $(this).is(":checked") ? $('.mceEditorWide').show() : $('.mceEditorWide').hide();
});


$(document).on('submit', $('form'), function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert($('.mceEditorWide').val());
})
```

There is a simpler implementation of showing/hiding the textarea AND when you submit the form, you can see the value of the textarea alerted.

Here's a working example:

https://jsfiddle.net/nebulousal/4bnjfLc8/

Also, you could insert your own code to intercept the form submission and do whatever you want to the actual data that is going to the server before it is sent:

```
$(document).on('submit', $('form'), function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  //Do whatever you want to do to any data in the form
  //Then send it off to the server
})
```

Comment: the problem is when the textarea is set to `display:none` then the value doesn't save. The code I have in the question works for hiding and showing the textarea. But the problem is saving the value